# Password protected REDIS with dependency injection nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, redis

Hey what's going on guys, I have a problem with the dependency injection on my Redis settings. We have an outdoor central Redis server for development, so in my main file (**app.js**) am I'm trying to connect this to the server. Now, this is password protected and can't find the isue.

I'm using this module [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

### app.js

```
let redis = require('redis');
let redisSettings = {
    host: settings.redis.ip,
    port: settings.redis.port,
    parser: settings.redis.parser,
    password: settings.redis.password
};

let redisClient = redis.createClient(redisSettings);
    redisClient.auth(settings.redis.password, function(){
});

let routes = require('./routes')( redisClient);
```

### settings.js

```
module.exports = {
    redis: {
        ip: 'domainname.example',
        port: '6379',
        parser: 'javascript',
        password: 'our_very_secure_password'
    }
}
```

### the error page

> events.js:182   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event   ^
>
> ReplyError: DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because
>   protected          mode is enabled, no bind address was specified, no
>   authentication password is requested to clients.  In this mode
>   connections are only accepted from the loopback interface.  If you
>   want to connect from external computers to Redis you may adopt  one of
>   the following solutions: 1)  Just disable protected mode sending the
>   command 'CONFIG SET protected- mode no' from the loopback  interface
>   by connecting to Redis from the same host the server is  running,
>   , however, MAKE SURE Redis is not publicly  accessible from internet if
>   you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE to make this change permanent. 2) 
>   Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing the 
>   Redis configuration file, and setting  the protected mode option to
>   'no', and then restarting the server. 3)  If you started the server
>   manually  just for testing, restart it with the '--protected-mode no'
>   option. 4)  Setup a bind address or an authentication password.  NOTE:
>   You only need to do one of the above things in order for the  server
>   to start accepting connections from the outside. at parseError 
>   (/Users/joey.dossche/Documents/DEV/koha_goan/node_modules/redis-
>   parser/lib/parser.js:193:12) at parseType 
>   (/Users/joey.dossche/Documents/DEV/koha_goan/node_modules/redis-
>   parser/lib/parser.js:303:14)
>
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: It's not an option to disable the Protection mode, in our situation is this required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question by myself in this time. It's really simple, there is no answer... It's impossible to and keeps the redis password protected and make it usable without binding IP addresses. So now we work with the security turned off and will reconnect the security settings if we enter the production stage.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 possible solutions to your problem included in the error log. You can use the one that is most convenient for you.